# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <service>. Apps targeting Android 12

Tags: java, android

[Tôi đang dặp rắc rối với nó](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9P1A.png)

android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. datlichkhambenh.app main manifest (this file)

Answer (score 0):

You must add exported attribute to your activities and services (entry points) of your app on AndroidManifest. Mostly it can be false, I used true just for notification service.